# Rails/ActiveRecord Average of DateTime Returns BigDecimal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sqlite

I'm writing a checkout system (like for a library), and I was trying to compute the average time that titles are checked out for using Ruby on Rails. The development database is SQLite3.

I call `records = Title.find(1).records.where('[in] IS NOT NULL')` to get a relation of records that have been returned (in is the DateTime when the title was checked back in). I'd like to be able to call `average_time = records.average(:in) - records.average(:out)`, but this is the output I get (from the rails console).

```
irb(main):023:0> average_time = records.average(:in) - records.average(:out)
   (0.3ms)  SELECT AVG("records"."in") FROM "records" WHERE "records"."title_id" = ? AND ([in] IS NOT NULL)  [["title_id", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  SELECT AVG("records"."out") FROM "records" WHERE "records"."title_id" = ? AND ([in] IS NOT NULL)  [["title_id", 1]]
=> #<BigDecimal:7fe104a4cd50,'0.0',9(18)>
```

I'd like to be able to fetch the average without selecting every in and out time and then averaging them in the actual app. The underlying problem seems to be that SQLite3 only returns the year.

```
sqlite> SELECT AVG("records"."in") FROM "records" WHERE "records"."title_id" = 1 AND ([in] IS NOT NULL);
2016.0

sqlite> SELECT AVG("records"."in" - "records"."out") FROM "records" WHERE "records"."title_id" = 1 AND ([in] IS NOT NULL);
0.0
```

(schema for reference)

```
sqlite> .schema records
CREATE TABLE "records" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "title_id" integer NOT NULL, "borrower" varchar NOT NULL, "note" text, "agent" varchar NOT NULL, "out" datetime NOT NULL, "in" datetime, "created_at" datetime NOT NULL, "updated_at" datetime NOT NULL, "due" datetime, "return_approved" datetime);
CREATE INDEX "index_records_on_title_id" ON "records" ("title_id");
```

This, however, does work.

```
sqlite> SELECT AVG(strftime("%s", "records"."in") - strftime("%s", "records"."out")) FROM "records" WHERE "records"."title_id" = 1 AND ([in] IS NOT NULL);
91290.0
```

Is the solution here to just forgoe the DateTime format and represent everything as integers representing epoch timestamps? Eventually, I believe the production environment will be MySQL.